Proof Without Axiom of Choice: Infiniteness of Union
Without using any form of the axiom of choice, prove that if $A$ is infinite, then the set $\bigcup A$ is also infinite.
I have encountered this proposition in my studies and find it intriguing, yet I'm struggling to prove it rigorously. Could someone kindly elucidate this result and provide a clear and concise proof?
Any assistance or guidance on this matter would be sincerely appreciated.

If you are working without choice you should probably specify what you mean by infinite.

Note that $A\subseteq\mathcal P(\bigcup A)$.
If $\bigcup A$ is finite, its power set is finite, so every subset of its power set is finite too.

I will also add that if you define infinite as being not Dedekind finite then your claim doesn't hold. Let $B$ be a Dedekind finite set that is infinite (the existence of such sets is consistent with $ZF$). If $\mathcal{P}(B)$ is Dedekind infinite then set $A=\mathcal{P}(B)$. In such can $A$ is Dedekind infinite but $\bigcup A=B$ is Dedekind finite.

Otherwise if $\mathcal{P}(B)$ is Dedekind finite, observe that the map $x\mapsto|x|$ defines a partial surjection from $\mathcal{P}(B)$ to $\omega$. This means that $\mathcal{P}(\omega)$ injects into $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(B))$ by taking preimages. To be more explicit, the map that sends $S\subseteq \omega$ to the set $\{t\subseteq B: |t|\in S\}$ is an injection from $\mathcal{P}(\omega)$ to $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(B))$. Set $A=\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(B))$. $A$ is Dedekind infinite since $\mathcal{P}(\omega)$ injects into it, but $\bigcup A=\mathcal{P}(B)$ which by assumption was Dedekind finite.
